# Other than polarization what hidden variables have been applied to pairs of particles to correlate them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, quantum-entanglement

Are there examples where correlated pairs where given certain specific variables or multiple variables in an attempt to produce the predictions of quantum mechanics?

Comment: Hi Bill. Are you thinking of properties like e.g. charge? i.e. if we produce an entangled electron and positron then both the negative and positive charge are present at both locations? If so note that entanglement produces a single system. When we entangle two particles they are no longer two particles but just a single system with the properties delocalised over the whole system.

Comment: John, particles with extra variables can be correlated and tested to show correlations matching QM or cos2theta. A bi-variable could be both polarization and a rotating cycle. Picture a knife rotating vertically as it moves along to the target. Of course the vertical polarization plays an important roll but the rotation does too. Place a vertical slot along the way and the knife has no problem. Place a horizontal slot and it's stopped. Rotate the slot to some angle in between and the knife may make it depending on where the rotation is when it it gets to the slot. It can match cos2theta.